# MPMoviePlayer play on when application goes Background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working with **iOS5**.

I am working on HTTPLivestream project .Here i am using **MPMovieplayer** ,my problem is when application goes to background there is no audio . i am changing the plist in background mode is audio.But there is no result please help me .

### AppDel

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  backgroundTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
  }];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
  });
}
```

### RadioControlView

```
  NSString *path =[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://*******/alayam/alayam/playlist.m3u8"];

  audioUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:path];

  appDelegate.player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
                                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                         selector:@selector(loadStateDidChange:) 
                                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification 
                                                           object:appDelegate.player];
                if ([appDelegate.player respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) 
                {
                    [appDelegate.player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeVolumeOnly];
                    [appDelegate.player setFullscreen:YES];
                    [appDelegate.player prepareToPlay];
                 }

- (void)loadStateDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
      {   
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:appDelegate.player];

      }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing on simulator, then it's doesn't work on simulator, please use device. If you are using device and audio is not playing in background, then can you please email me your complete source code at khalid0491@gmail.com. I have also done in my Application.
My code is given below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
}
```

and in plist i made an array named "Required background mode" and insert an item in array name, "App Plays Audio".

Comment: Have you properly added in Plist??? First time I added String outside the Array "Required Background Modes" rather than inside array. Please coinfirm it.

Comment: awesome Mr.Khalid Usman ...its working than q so much spend u r valuable time. Problem is the plist

Comment: No, Problem! You should also vote up on the specific plist related comment, perhaps it will help someone else. Thanks

Comment: @Khalidi   Just edit u r code..Add below lines (Must)       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier newTaskId = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    newTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

Comment: @Nag_iphone, Don't need to unmark the accepted answer. I have just paste the simplest code, for your understanding, otherwise I have implemented it and others. And for your information, it's not necessary to put code of like [UIApplication sharedApplication] in ViewDidLoad, you can do it anywhere according to your logic, my code is working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do remote control setting in combination with Background support setting in ios5-

// register your app for remote control

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];


// allows you to play in the background when app is suspended in iOS5
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Place both the settings in application didFinishLaunching delegate

Comment: Remote control setting has nothing to to with the audio session configuration in general!

Comment: thanks for replay but still not working ..is it possible movie player working on background

Comment: Yes you are right when you are working till ios4 ,But in iOS5 , we need both the settings (remote control and background setting) for background audio support.

Answer (score 1):

Try to activate the audio session **before** initializing the player, e.g. in the app launch delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
  NSError *error = nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];

  // other init stuff ...
}
```

PS: You need to be on the device for audio sessions to work, Simulator won't cut it.

Comment: thanks for replay but still not working ,is it possible movie player working on background

Comment: @Nag - if you want only audio, than you can use AVAudioPlayer instead of MPMoviePlayer.